# "An error occurred during local report processing" after save file at first time by using savefiledialog

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a problem that i can't find in the Google search. I try to solve by myself but still not working. I have to render report and export to excel.
The problem is when i save file at first time, it works fine. But when i save file a second time, it shows "An error occurred during local report processing"

Here is my code

```
        public void createReportExcel(List<Models.MachineTime> item, List<Models.TestTime> testTime, List<Models.Interval> interval)
    {
        ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer(); 
        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../../Report/Scale.rdlc";
        string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", item);
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", testTime);
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource2);
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource3 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet3", interval);
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource3);
        string reportType = null;
        string deviceInfo = null;
        reportType = "Excel";
        deviceInfo =
          "<DeviceInfo>" +
          "  <OutputFormat>Excel</OutputFormat>" +
          "  <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>" +
          "  <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>" +
          "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
          "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
          "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
          "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
          "</DeviceInfo>";
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension; 
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes= null;
        string mimeType; 
            renderedBytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings); 
        SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile.Filter = "Excel file (*.xls)|*.xls"; 
        if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string saveFileName = saveFile.FileName;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@saveFileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
                viewer.Dispose();
            } 
        } 
    }
```

As i explained, it works fine when i saved at first time. when i tried to save again, the error will occur at line

```
renderedBytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
```

i noticed that when i successfully save after a dialog show at first time, the second time, the error will always occur. If i cancel at first time while dialog showing, it has no problem at the second time.

I also tried to remove this line

```
        string saveFileName = saveFile.FileName;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@saveFileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
                viewer.Dispose();
            }
```

The problem is still not solved.

Sorry for my bad English. I try to explain clearly so it may be ambiguous and wrong sentences. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have already edited.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

I have add this line

```
saveFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

It works fine! But i don't know why.